# Issues while extracting Industry/Sector from Yahoo finance package

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have to change my question subject to reflect my real issue.

If I try the below example with 3 stocks, the code is working fine. However, if I add more tickers, I am getting 'Key error'. Please help.

Code:

```
stocks = ['ADSK', 'DDD', 'DM', 'FARO', 'MTLS', 'SSYS', 'XONE', 'AAPL', 'NXTG', 'QCOM']
    
    import yfinance as yf
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for stock in stocks:
        info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
        industry = info['industry']
        beta = info['beta']
        sector = info['sector']
        df = df.append({'Stock':stock,'Industry':industry,'Beta':beta,'Sector':sector}, ignore_index=True)
```

Error is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-8ae147fa8723> in <module>
      7 for stock in stocks:
      8     info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
----> 9     industry = info['industry']
     10     beta = info['beta']
     11     sector = info['sector']

KeyError: 'industry'
```

Comment: looks like a list - not a string

Comment: What does this have to do with Pandas?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "I want to see ...".
Those two snippets are the same list of strings, merely shown in different formats.

Comment: I have a big list and it is displaying in the 1st format. Is there a way I can convert the 2nd format?

Comment: @Murali What's the code? You didn't add the code?

Comment: I've run your code. I get an error with 'NXTG'. I think that the industry data is not registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NXTG stock doesn't have neither "industry", nor "beta" fields. Dictionary method `get()` could be used to avoid KeyError:

```
stocks = ['ADSK', 'DDD', 'DM', 'FARO', 'MTLS', 'SSYS', 'XONE', 'AAPL', 'NXTG', 'QCOM']
    
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in stocks:
  info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
  industry = info.get('industry')
  beta = info.get('beta')
  sector = info.get('sector')
  df = df.append({'Stock':stock,'Industry':industry,'Beta':beta,'Sector':sector}, ignore_index=True)

df
```

That will give following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It did help big time :-)